# how to show am/pm in 24 hours format in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an application in which I let users choose their language, after choosing the language it will also change the dates and time according to the the country's date format.

I do so by a NSDateFormatter.- [dateFormatter  setDateFormat:.....];
for english-US - I use "h:mm a" - to show am/pm settings.

PROBLEM IS: the am pm are only shown if my iPhone is on 12 hours mode, 
I guess it's because it automatically checks for the iPhone's time format, 
is there a way to override this? that the am/pm will show as well in 24 mode.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"H:mm a";
```

Example:

```
// Set up formatter
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"H:mm a";

// Print test date
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:8900];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Output:

```
14:23 PM
```

Comment: And according to your "language choosing" feature: Why don't you use Apples built in localization features? See [Guidelines for Internationalization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/InternationalGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002142-BBCFJBFB)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss a"];
NSString *date = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSArray *foo1 = [date componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];


NSRange amRange = [date rangeOfString:[formatter AMSymbol]];
NSRange pmRange = [date rangeOfString:[formatter PMSymbol]];
BOOL is24h = (amRange.location == NSNotFound && pmRange.location == NSNotFound);

NSArray *foo2 = [[foo1 objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
int hour = [[foo2 objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
int minute = [[foo2 objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
int second = [[foo2 objectAtIndex:2] intValue];

BOOL isAM = NO;

if (is24h) {
    if (hour >= 12) {
        isAM = NO;
    } else {
        isAM = YES;
    }
} else {
    isAM = [[foo1 objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"AM"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to customize your date format for a user-facing string because the presets for `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` don't cut it for you, the appropriate way to do this is to use [`setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1417087-setlocalizeddateformatfromtempla) with "j" or "jj" for the hours depending on whether you want zero padding (in regions that use that style, presumably — so far it seems to always leave out zero padding but I am guessing it is region-dependent).

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("jj:mm")
```

If the user is in a region that uses 24 hour time by default and/or they have 24 hour time turned on (via the switch in iOS Settings) it will output strings like "17:53". Otherwise it will output strings like "5:53 PM".

Note if you are overriding `locale` on your formatter be sure to set it before calling `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate`.

The template approach will automatically localize your strings to use the appropriate styling.

More information can be found in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) under "Working With User-Visible Representations of Dates and Times".